# fsck on root partition on BBB based custom board

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, ext4, fsck

We have BeagleBone Black based custom Embedded Linux Board.
It has Linux-3.12, 256MB RAM and 4GB eMMC with `ext4` file system on it.

Sometimes we run into file system errors(rare but not impossible). So we want to check for the file system errors and fix it at boot-up.
Obviously we don't want fsck or any other utility to destroy any data on file system.

We have busybox based `SysVinit` so `/forcefsck` doesn't work :(
Then I used `/etc/fstab`(setting 5th field to 1) and then running `fsck -p` from the `rcS` script.

This combination works for partitions other than `rootfs` partition.
I have couple question regarding that.

1. Is there anyway to run `fsck` on the `rootfs` partition?
2. Can `fsck -p` can destroy data on the partition ?
3. Is there any better way to handle this situation, I mean any service which will check and correct file system error ?

Answer (score 1):

The normal way for desktop Linux distributions based on SysVinit is to ask for a root password during boot when it detects errors on the root filesystem. You can then use this to run `fsck` on the root fs. I don't know if your embedded distro does this, but it's definitely possible to configure it that way.

If there are no errors detected during boot, another option is to login as root, stop everything that's not really necessary, remount the root filesystem read-only and then run fsck on it.

This is about the root filesystem of your block storage, not *rootfs*. Rootfs is a minimal ram-based filesystem that is used during boot, and it can't be corrupt (unless your boot kernel image is corrupt, or your RAM is bad).

In principle `fsck -p` is meant to do only "safe" repairs, but if you really want to make sure nothing bad happens, run it manually so you'll be prompted for each action. If there's for some reason valuable data on the root filesystem (shouldn't happen, but maybe you do), make a backup using `dd` first.

Comment: Thank you for reply dirkt. We are using only root user in our board. We don't multiuser system as yet. We don't even have initramfs/ramdisk we directly boot from block device root file system.

Comment: Root or multiuser doesn't really matter, it depends on how the sysv init is set up. Modern linux kernels have an initramfs that's embedded in the image, I don't know what image you use. If you really end up with `/` as the (ram-based) rootfs that's used during boot as root on modern kernels, as I said, there's really no way that can get corrupted, because it's created fresh every time. If your kernel is set up to use some block device as root, then that's different. It all depends on how your kernel is set up, which I can't see from here.

Comment: I could run `fsck -q` from `rcS` (busybox based) And that fixed the error in current root partition. However for that to happen we need to have an entry in `/etc/fstab`. Meanwhile now I am looking to test different kinds of file system errors possible and see if it can be fixed by `fsck` or not.